# Python code tabs not recognised between windows and linux

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adobe-brackets

I am using a windows computer to write some python code and I upload it to my raspberry.

I use notepad++ on my computer and adobe brackets. In Adobe brackets, when I do 1 tab, it aligns it so the indentation is correct for python (for example, I hit tab only once and it is aligning as if it was 4 tabs). In notepad++ I can see 4 tabs.

But when I upload it to my raspberry which is linux and I use nano to see the file, I only see 1 tab instead of 4. That gives me of course a lot of errors.

Thanks if you can help,

John.

Comment: You should be using 4 spaces not tabs for Python

Comment: Don't use tabs at all, use spaces.

Comment: Yes, use spaces instead of TABs. You can configure Notepad++ to expand TABs (so that it insert spaces when you press the TAB-key). `Settings -> Preferences -> Tab Settings -> Check "Replace by space"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard tabs are interpreted as different characters on windows and linux. You should always use spaces for Python.  You can use `reindent.py` to fix it on Windows and then it should work on both.  This script should be located in your Python install directory. Usage is:

```
reindent.py badcode.py
```

Comment: Please do explain why it's interpreted differently under Windows and Linux. Isn't a TAB-character just 0x9, '\t'?

Comment: Yeah, but Windows (default at least) equates a tab to 4 spaces and linux to 8 spaces.  I think theoretically it could work if you had all tabs in your file (and no spaces), but once you start mixing them, when you move it to linux, you're going to have problems.

Comment: It would depend on which text editor you use. Windows and Linux aren't text editors. Yes, using only TABs is OK, but you may not mix TABs and spaces. Atleast not in Python 3. See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces